# how to give jquery modals different position (not always centered)

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok so I'm using this [colorbox modal](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) and I've a clickable list of names as follows:

- Fred
- Richard
- David
- Pere
- Dase
- Feea

now when a user clicks on Fred, or any other name, I want to display colorbox modal on top of it much like [norton's website](http://us.norton.com/downloads/) (when you click the `quick view`) so that my modal is not boringly centered on the page but positioned relative to the clicked list item. I agree you can achieve this by giving each `<li>` a class and working on them but considering I have more than `40 names` doing this will only lead to a bulky code. How can I achieve this friends with the least amount of code i.e centering the modal relative to the list item (NB:-using css position relative doesn't work as preferred)?